# IPC: Shared Memory Access Restrict for particular process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I'm new to Linux IPC concepts in C. When a shared memory is created by a process. That Shm can be accessed by any other processes also. Consider the following figure,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8ix5.jpg
  or
 http://s14.postimg.org/5zpgstuvl/shared.jpg

If 4 process named A,B,C,D are running on a system and a shared memory is created by A.
Is there any **mechanism or concept** to restrict the access of shm to only A and D and disallow the access to B and C (even they have the key of the shared memory).

Here, Access means "Read only / Read-Write".

Little help is appreciated...

Thanking you.

Comment: Yes, the permissions in `shmget` (sysv) or `shm_open` (posix)

Comment: - Thanks for the reply Mr.Duck
- So a user who created a shared memory for a process can create some other process to access that shared memory.  Right?
- If the permissions are given for the same user. Other users cannot access that memory? Isn't it?

Comment: Right.  Like file permissions, access can be granted by user, group and world.